# How many $7$-digit telephone numbers with distinct digits starting with $927$ are there?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A telephone number consist of seven digits. How many phone numbers with distinct digits starting with 927 are there?

I answered $10^4$. Is that correct?

Comment: You're _not_ correct. Your solution counts phone numbers with repeated digits too.

Comment: What attempt lead you to obtain the supposed answer of $10^4$?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: In which country do you live cause the number of digits in a phone number vary according to country. As per your solution it seems that the phone number in your country is of 7 digits. Is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since those numbers start with $927$ and the numbers are distinct you only can choose among $\{0,1,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ distinctively $4$ more digits. Therefore the total number of such phone numbers is $$4!\binom{7}{4}=\dfrac{7!}{3!}=840$$

Comment: I cannot upvote because I reached my daily limit and have to wait a couple of hours, but someone upvote because this guy has $4,999$ reputation! #ParkerSquare

Comment: here it is, 5000 now!

Comment: Hahah that’s funny :))

Comment: Yeah! Sounds crazy!!!

Answer (score 3):

Gimusi's answer is right, but just to give you a little more insight:

Whenever you need to choose $p$ elements from a set of $n$ elements, and the order you choose them matter, there are:

$\frac{n!}{(n-p)!}$ possibilities

In this problem, you have to choose 4 numbers from a set of 7, so you get:

$\frac{7!}{3!} = 840$

Comment: Thanks for the quote!

Comment: Sometimes, I need answers like these to not get confused with combinations and permutations.

Comment: @user477343 in this case I think that the rule of product is the best way to see it in a simpler way

Comment: What i stated is a general form of the rule of product for these kinds of combinations, something that is oftem helpful to know for harder problems.

Comment: @gimusi Well I can’t argue with you there, haha. It’s just that for me personally, combinatorics and probability, along with inequalities, are my worst.

Answer (score 2):

We have the first 3 digits fixed and the last 4 to be chosen among 7 (0,1,3,4,5,6,8) then, since the **digits are distinct**, we have

- 7 choices for the first
- 6 choices for the second
- 5 choices for the third
- 4 choices for the fourth

Now apply the [Rule of Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) to obtain

$$7\cdot 6 \cdot 5\cdot 4=840$$

Comment: there is no statement in the problem that says I can't use 927 in the 4 slots

Comment: @LeonzoEscolar the statement "how many phone numbers with distinct digits starting with 927 are there?" corrsponds exactly to my assumptions

Comment: Since the digits are **distinct** then of course $927$ can’t be included in the $4$ slots because it is already fixed as the first $3$ digits.

Comment: oh right yeah I'm sorry